# NODEJS ,DROPBOX redirection LINK

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to know if its possible to open using nodeJS a link(number 1) that lead to second(link number 2) then retrieve the url of the second one.
the purpose behind this is that i want to use this operation to retrieve a direct link from the shared link of **DROPBOX**.the shared redirect me to another link which a need to operate some modification on it to get the direct link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're trying to get a direct link from a shared link, you can just change the domain name from `www.dropbox.com` to `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`. See https://www.dropbox.com/developers/blog/53/programmatically-download-content-from-share-links.

**EDIT**:

And if you really do need to follow a redirect first, try something like this:

```
var http = require('http');

var url = '...';
http.get(url, function (res) {
    if (res.statusCode === 301 || res.statusCode === 302) {
        console.log('Redirected to: ' + res.headers.location);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

You can find some interesting modules that helps you with that:

For an example:

- https://github.com/mikeal/request
- https://github.com/assaf/zombie